# Share Pass not displaying as an option on some iPhone devices

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet, passkit

I've got an iPhone 6s running 12.1.4 and SharingProhibited = false is set when generating the pass. The back of the pass shows Share Pass on my device and I'm able to click on the button to bring up the Share options dialogue. We've tested with some other devices. One is running iOS 13.3 (iPhone Xs) and the other is running 13.3.1 (iPhone 11) and the Share Pass option does not display.

My code. :)

```
pass.SharingProhibited = false;
```

Is anyone else having this issue?

Has the field been changed in iOS 13+?

If I set pass.SharingProhibited = true, it works as expected on all test devices. The Share Pass option is not displayed.

There appear to be no changes between iOS 12 and 13 posted here.
https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/add-and-manage-passes-iphe7aa3336/13.0/ios/13.0

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to test, personally, on a 13.3.1 device today. We were able to share the pass. It looks like the Share Pass language has been removed in iOS 13x. Now, you have to click on the up arrow, located on the upper right-hand side of the back of the pass to share it.